# Vigenere cipher in cs50 Segfau

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

I am not experienced coder.Please dont judge for bad styling.I've run into an issue with the vingenere cipher
It keeps giving me segfau

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>**

int main(int argc,string argv[])
    {
       while (argc!=2)
       {
        printf("Incorrect input\n");
        return 1;
       }

    printf("plaintext:");
    string plaintext=get_string();

    string num=argv[1];
    int keylength=strlen(num);

    for (int j=0, n=strlen(plaintext); j<n; j++)
    {
        char letter=plaintext[j];
        if (isalpha(letter))
        {
```

This is the reason of Segmantation Fault error.
If i don't check if num is upper or lower case,
code runs normally.

> ```
> if (isupper(letter))
>             {
>                 if (isupper(num))
>                 {
>                     printf ("%c",((((letter-65)+(num[j%keylength]-65))%26)+65));
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     printf ("%c",((((letter-65)+(num[j%keylength]-97))%26)+65));
>                 }
>              }
>             else
>             {
>                 if (isupper(num))
>                 {
>                     printf ("%c",((((letter-97)+(num[j%keylength]-65))%26)+97));
>                 }
>
>                else
>               {
>                    printf ("%c",((((letter-97)+(num[j%keylength]-97))%26)+97));
>                }
>            }
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             printf ("%c",letter);
>         }
> ```

```
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `isupper(num)` ??

Comment: Note: Don't use _magic numbers_. Why don't you use character constants `A` etc.? Your code is quite obfuscated. That is not just a matter of style. And use library functions where available.

Comment: I agree, should'v used character constants.But that can't be the case

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it checks if KEY is uppercase or lower

Comment: @Gio `num` is `string num`, not character.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes that is the case. I see now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you meant

```
if (isupper(num[j % keylength))
```

Passing a string (really a `char *`) to `isupper()` is an undefined operation, and may produce weird effects depending on how `isupper()` is implemented.  The GNU implementation ---

```
#define __ctype_lookup(__c) ((__ctype_ptr__+sizeof(""[__c]))[(int)(__c)])
#define isupper(__c) ((__ctype_lookup(__c)&(_U|_L))==_U)
```

--- uses a lookup table with all sorts of fun pointer math and casting under the hood, so it likely allows a `char *` to be passed without the compiler complaining, but it's definitely not going to produce good results.  Change your `if` statement, and it should work better.

Comment: It's clear now.Thanks